# How to log a message when logging turned off in configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, logging

I am debugging some custom code on the live high traffic Magento 1.9 site.

I don't want to turn on logging in `System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings` as the log file is filling up with messages so fast I can't see my debug message.

Is there a command that will log a message with logging turned off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Mage::log('message',null,'logfile.log',true);
```

That will log `message` text in `var/log/logfile.log` no matter if logging is turned on or off.

Comment: Konstantin Gerasimov thank you for your prompt reply. Let me try that

Comment: Maybe it is good to mention that the 4th parameters, which you set to `true` is used to force the log, no matter if development mode is true or not.